# Hobby Motor RPM

Tags: dc-motor

So I want to know if my [motor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11696) is fast enough for my project and the tutorial says: 100 RPM. On the [datasheet](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/M260.pdf) it says: "No load speed：6600±10%rpm". Is this fast enough? I know it means without a load but it's a tiny load.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Noah, but you need to clarify your question. 6600 RPM is 66 x 100 RPM. It would seem most obvious that this is way too fast for your application. What is your real question? Put all the details **in your question** and not in the comments.

Comment: It means that motor needs something like 50:1 speed reduction gearbox to match your application. (Would be 66:1 but it'll slow down some under load)

Comment: You will have to explain your application a bit better. If your tutorial is freely accessible online, please post a link to it so we can help you. If not, please update your post with the details so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That motor is 66 times as fast as required for your project: 6600 RPM vs 100 RPM.

Comment: But what does the ±10% mean

Comment: @Noah The ±10% means that the no load speed can vary from 5940 RPM to 7260 RPM depending on the motor. The reason is since the motor is a low cost device, the manufacturing process allows for some variation as not every motor can be built exactly the same for economic reasons.